# wedge product/cross product

Tags: cross-product, exterior-algebra

I am currently practising the wedge product, but I don't quite understand the structer overall. There is a task in my textbook marked "easy". Could anyone help me with this? I think an example would help me a lot.

> Let $V$ be a real vector space, $\dim V=3, \ \ \sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3$ a basis of $V^*$, $\omega=\sum a_i \sigma_i, \ \ \eta=\sum b_i \sigma_i$ two random elements of $V^*$.
>
> Calculate $\omega \wedge \eta$ and give reasons why the wedge product is a generalization of the cross product.

Let $v,w \in V$. I know that then:
$$(\omega \wedge \eta)(v,w)=\omega(v)\eta(w)-\omega(w)\eta(v)$$
But where is the connection to the cross product?

Comment: You're having trouble seeing a connection, but [this person cannot tell the difference](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4720/29335). Maybe that post can give you some inspiration :)

Comment: Yes I also found a related post as posted by rschwieb, but @newbie can you state the book you are following, just out of curiosity and resource collector :)

Comment: observe that $\sigma^2\wedge\sigma^3(v,w)=v_2w_3-v_3w_2$ which is the first component of the cross $v\times w$

Comment: and ordering $$\sigma^2\wedge\sigma^3$$ $$\sigma^3\wedge\sigma^1$$ $$\sigma^1\wedge\sigma^2$$ for basics bivector  you would have $$a_2b_3-a_3b_2$$ as a first component of $\omega\wedge\eta$

Comment: Wedge product is not related to cross product unless you have an inner product and [Hodge star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator) on $V$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $$\omega=a_1\sigma^1+a_2\sigma^2+a_3\sigma^3$$
and
$$\eta=b_1\sigma^1+b_2\sigma^2+b_3\sigma^3$$ then
$$\omega\wedge\eta=
(a_2b_3-a_3b_2)\sigma^2\wedge\sigma^3
+(a_3b_1-a_1b_3)\sigma^3\wedge\sigma^1
+(a_1b_2-a_2b_1)\sigma^1\wedge\sigma^2
,$$
which has another meaning of
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\end{array}\right)\times\left(\begin{array}{c}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{c}a_2b_3-a_3b_2\\a_3b_1-a_1b_3\\a_1b_2-a_2b_1\end{array}\right),$$
however both have the same components.

Comment: also it could be thought as the known use $$(a_1i+a_2j+a_3k)\times(b_1i+b_2j+b_3k)=c_1i+c_2j+c_3k,$$ where  $$c_1=a_2b_3-a_3b_2,$$ $$c_2=a_3b_1-a_1b_3,$$ $$c_3=a_1b_2-a_2b_1,$$ as commonly used in the "vector-calculus" symbology

Comment: Is there any reasoning why the resulting vector of the cross product starts with the coefficients of $\sigma^2 \wedge \sigma^3$?

Comment: For the cross product always is as this. With 1 and 2 forms, there in vector calculus, the operation $d(Adx+Bdy+Cdz)$, the exterior derivative of the 1-form $Adx+Bdy+Cdz$ is $$d(Adx+Bdy+Cdz)=(C_y-B_z)dy\wedge dz+(A_z-C_x)dz\wedge dx+(B_x-A_x)dx\wedge dy$$ is present in the corresponding Stokes' Theorem.

Comment: @mnp here $A_x=\dfrac{\partial A}{\partial x}$, etc.